# Mongoose doesn't create index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two schemas - User & Conversation - in a node/express/mongoose project. I've added indexes on each schema. When checking the indexes in my (free) Mongo Atlas Cluster, I can see that Conversation's index is created. However, User doesn't create the required indexes.

Here is my User Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    age: { type: String},
    location: {
      type: { type: String, enum: ["Point"], default: "Point" },
      coordinates: { type: [Number], default: [0, 0] },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);


userSchema.index({ age: 1, location: "2dsphere", username: 1 });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

In Mongo Atlas, there are two indexes on the users collection: `id` (of course), and `email`. I never asked to index email. `age`, `location`, and `username` are not indexed. How to fix this?

Comment: Don't rely  on mongoose to create indexes, just create them manually.

Comment: How can you create index manually in a express/mongoose project? I only have a mongoose.connect function and a few schemas. Where am I supposed to instance them?

Comment: In mongoshell https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the mongoose documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) you can do the field level indexing within your Schema at the path level.
For example if you need to index age, you can do as below within your schema:

```
age: { type: String, index: true},
```

You are trying to make a compound index in your code which consists of a 2dsphere index. I guess this is not what you want.

Comment: So I've added the index at the field level, but still it doesn't work. When checking my atlas cluster, the only indexes are id and email, though I've requested age, location and username. I have written: age: { type: Number, default: null, index: true }, location: {
      type: { type: String, enum: ["Point"], default: "Point" },
      coordinates: { type: [Number], default: [0, 0], index: "2dsphere" },
    }. I really don't understand why no index is created.

Comment: I tested this, it works fine and all the indexes are created, email is indexed because of the unique property that you are using. There is nothing wrong with the schema, I guess you should look for the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Ok I've made it work, but I don't know how. I wrote  User.ensureIndexes(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
}); somewhere in the script, and voilà. Wtf.